Ser consciente and Estar consciente- difference between them and possible discrepancies
I hate posing a ''ser' versus ''estar'' question but here it is nonetheless.
According to EL CASTELLLANO:
¿Ser consciente o estar consciente?
Consulta:
¿Soy consciente o estoy consciente? ¿Cual es la forma correcta?
Respuesta:
Para expresar que una persona 'tiene conocimiento de algo, esp. de sus actos, de sus sentimientos o de sus pensamientos', se emplean ambas expresiones: ser consciente, de uso mayoritario en España; y estar consciente, de uso mayoritario en América: Soy/Estoy consciente de que actué sin diplomacia. Pero para expresar que una persona está 'en pleno uso de sus sentidos y facultades' se usa solo estar consciente: Después del accidente, estuvo siete días en coma, pero ahora está completamente consciente.
So, it explains that in Sapin ,at least, ser is used to be aware of something,like a situation or thoughts of their own or others. Estar consciente seems to be conscious after an accident,not to be in a coma.
As far as I can see Word Reference sources agree with this :
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ser-estar-consciente.236300/
When I check in Spanishdict examples,however, I see that it is mainly in agreement .
https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/i%20am%20aware%20that
However,it gives the following examples which are not the same .
Estoy consciente de que otros están teniendo experiencias similares.
Estoy al tanto de que el piloto reportó un OVNI.
Estoy consciente de que tú tienes la pintura real.
Could these be Latin-American examples or am I missing something else here?

In my experience as a Latin American speaker, "ser consciente" means "be aware" while "estar consciente" means "be conscious".

@Gustavson. Interesting.That seems to be the broadly accepted idea .As I said, some sources stated that the reverse is true in Latin-America. Maybe in some places ,obviously not where you are from.

It's not that "estar consciente" sounds altogether wrong to me to mean "be aware", but it is much less common and, in my view, only used to refer to a continued state of awareness.

@Gustavson . Really, a continued state of awareness, being  something ongoing ,I thought would use "ser" as it is more permanent. But, I suppose it is not a state but rather a continuous activity.

I dunno if I should bother posting the whole thing but it is very well explained here: https://www.rae.es/dpd/conciencia El adjetivo consciente se construye con el verbo estar cuando significa 'que no se ha perdido el conocimiento': «Su vida no corre peligro y está consciente, según el parte médico» (Vanguardia [Esp.] 2.6.1995); y con el verbo ser cuando significa 'saber algo o tener conciencia de ello': «Rivas […] es consciente de que en la cita olímpica estarán los mejores»

You should always check the RAE. You can do it like this: ser consciente site:rae.es So, estar consciente is to be conscious (phyically). estar consciente is to be aware of something or be conscious of something. In English, there are two ways to say the same thing for the estar one.

@Lambie That is fine, "ser consciente" is to be aware and "estar consciente"  is to be conscious physically speaking, in broad terms, thank you for the link!

No existe norma unívoca para escoger ser / estar, pero si tuviera que describir alguna sería esta:


Estar suele estar vinculado con un estado temporal.
Ser suele estar vinculado con un estado atemporal.


Ejemplos:


Estamos en Hawaii de vacaciones.
Somos de Hawaii, nacimos en Honolulu.




Soy diabético. (la diabetes tiene tratamiento, pero no tiene cura)
Estoy resfriado. (se pasará en unos días)




Ahora está consciente. Ha despertado después de desmayarse.
Él es consciente de sus actos.


La connotación temporal (estar) o atemporal (ser) la decide el sujeto.


Soy Casado (Hasta el fin de los días, en lo bueno y en lo malo)
Estoy Casado (Algún dia quizás me quedo viudo, me separo, etc.)


Cuando la regla de temporalidad / atemporalidad no se cumple, puede buscarse connotación en la evolución de la lengua, quedarse en un sitio siempre no era frecuente.


Soy de Venezuela (Ser de Venezuela, no cambiará)
Estoy en Venezuela (Estar en Venezuela, no sabes si durará para siempre)
Estoy en La Tierra (Estar en un lugar, históricamente era algo temporal. Aunque no seamos astronautas, estamos en La Tierra.)


